# Extraer datos de la base de datos y mostrarlos en el input como opción, asi como hace Google cuando estas haciendo una busqueda

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un navegador tipo Google. Pero tengo una duda, ¿Cómo extraigo datos de una base de datos SQL y los muestro como opción cuando un usuario está tecleando una búsqueda en el input? Así como hace Google. Se que hay una consulta a SQL de la cual obtienes un objeto.

Bien, acá encontré un código averiguando por Internet, que hace lo que quiero.

Este es el php

```
$sugerencias = array(
    0 => 'como robar a bill gates',
    1 => 'como ser guay sin robar a bill gates',
    2 => 'bill gates es alienigena',
    3 => 'esto no tiene nada que ver con el resto',
    4 => 'tengo un cuerno de mamut y te lo meto por el cu..',
    5 => 'cuerno de cabra'
);

if(isset($_GET['busqueda'])){
    $busqueda = preg_quote($_GET['busqueda'], '~');
    $resultado = preg_grep('~'.$busqueda.'~', $sugerencias);

    die(json_encode($resultado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

}

?>
```

Este es el HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>
    <title>Buscador</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete/gh-pages/awesomplete.css'>
</head>
<body>

    <form action='busqueda.php' method='GET'>
        <input type='text' id="busqueda" class="a" name='busqueda' placeholder='Busca algo!'>
        <button type='submit'>Buscar</button>
    </form>

<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete/gh-pages/awesomplete.min.js'></script>
<script src='sugerencias.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esto es Ajax
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

```
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(a, {
        minChars: 3, // solo se dan sugerencias si hay 3 o más letras escritas.
        maxItems: 10, // numero maximo de sugerencias a mostrar
        autoFirst: true
    });

    a.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
        if (this.value.length < awesomplete.minChars) { return true; }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'busqueda.php?busqueda=' + a.value);
        xhr.onload = function(){

            if(xhr.status !== 200){
                console.log('El request ha fallado. ' + xhr.status);
            }

            // Le pasamos la lista de autocompletado obtenido de php a Awesomplete
            awesomplete.list = Object.values(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        };
        xhr.send();
    });

}, false);
```

Es una librería que me recomendaron, que lo que hace es ir mostrando sugerencias de una búsqueda que se hace, pero como ven ya los datos están en un arreglo, y yo lo que quiero es extraerlos desde la base de datos.

Otra cosa, esa librería tiene estilos CSS personalizados que sin ellos no nace el efecto que quiero, así que cuando intento sobrescribir esos estilos con bootstrap entonces el script deja de funcionar ¿Alguien se le ocurre como remediar eso?

Comment: Cambia la lógica dentro de `if(isset($_GET['busqueda'])){`conectandote a una bbdd y usando `LIKE` en la query. Si no sabes como conectar a mysql desde php lo mejor la guia oficial http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la solución ya implementada, solo te falta darte cuenta que el array que tienes con textos fijos debes obtenerlo de la base de datos en vez de escribir tu cada fila. No te voy a escribir el código pero te voy a indicar la idea.

deberías cambiar esto

```
$sugerencias = array(
0 => 'como robar a bill gates',
1 => 'como ser guay sin robar a bill gates',
2 => 'bill gates es alienigena',
3 => 'esto no tiene nada que ver con el resto',
4 => 'tengo un cuerno de mamut y te lo meto por el cu..',
5 => 'cuerno de cabra');
```

por algo así

```
//EN ESTE ENLACE PUEDES VER COMO OBTENER UN ARREGLO DESDE LA BD
```

http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/mostrar-un-array-de-una-base-de-datos-mysql-con-php-c42674l/

```
$sugerencias = mostrarMatriz(filtro_sugerencias);

if(isset($_GET['busqueda'])){
  $busqueda = preg_quote($_GET['busqueda'], '~');
  $resultado = preg_grep('~'.$busqueda.'~', $sugerencias);

  die(json_encode($resultado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

}

?>
```

Comment: Ese tutorial usa una libreria de php para mysql obsoleta y no recomendable. Mejor mysqli o pdo

Comment: yo uso pdo, y eso que dice filtro_sugerencias, el parámetro ese que es? una variable o que?